# Apache Rendering 403 error

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm trying to create a cookbook for installing Wordpress. Everything seems to be ok, except when visiting the sight I get a 403 error. `You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

#### default.rb

```
include_recipe 'wp::httpd'
include_recipe 'mariadb'
# include_recipe 'wp::mysql'
include_recipe 'wp::wordpress'
```

#### httpd.rb

```
directory(node[:wp][:app_root])

web_app(node[:wp][:app_name]) do
  server_name(node[:wp][:server_name])
  docroot(node[:wp][:app_root])
  template('vhost.conf.erb')
end
```

#### wordpress.rb

```
ruby_block 'install_wordpress' do
  block do
    require 'fileutils'
    FileUtils.cd node[:wp][:app_root]
    system 'wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz'
    system 'tar -xzf latest.tar.gz --strip-components=1 && rm latest.tar.gz'
  end
  not_if { ::File.exist?(File.join(node[:wp][:app_root], 'wp-settings.php')) }
  action :create
end

template("#{node[:wp][:app_root]}/wp-config.php") do
  source('wp-config.php.erb')
  variables(
    db_name: node[:wp][:app_name],
    db_user: node[:wp][:app_name],
    db_password: node[:wp][:db_password]
  )
end

execute 'set_apache_as_owner' do
  command "chown #{node['apache']['user']} -R #{node[:wp][:app_root]}"
end
```

#### templates/default/vhost.conf.erb

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName <%= @params[:server_name] %>
  DocumentRoot <%= @params[:docroot] %>

  <Directory <%= @params[:docroot] %>>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  LogLevel info
  ErrorLog <%= @node[:apache][:log_dir] %>/<%= @params[:name] %>-error.log
  CustomLog <%= @node[:apache][:log_dir] %>/<%= @params[:name] %>-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some authz lines in there to allow access to the docroot. Usually that would be `Require all granted` in the `Directory` block for Apache 2.4.